# Deleting or Updating SQL Record

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-delete

I have a table with following two fields

```
jobid |  statusCode
```

Now here is what I want to do, I want to "delete the reocrd with given jobid if statusCode is less than some value, otherwise update this record with new statusCode"

My question is is there some single SQL operation to perform above mentioned job or do I have to use multiple SQL "if - else" sort of queries. My DB is SQlite3

Regards,
Farrukh Arshad.

Comment: there will only be 1 if-else used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has a command [UPDATE OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) that combines updating and inserting, but this is only for the common case where you want to avoid inserting a duplicate.

The [DELETE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) command does not have the functionality you want.

SQLite does not have any control flow statements, so your best bet is to execute both DELETE/UPDATE statements:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE jobid = ?
  AND statusCode < ?;

UPDATE MyTable
SET statusCode = ?
WHERE jobid = ?;        -- does nothing if record was deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
CASE WHEN status_code < some_value 
THEN
  DELETE FROM MyTable
  WHERE jobid = ?
ELSE
  UPDATE MyTable
  SET statusCode = ?
  WHERE jobid = ?
END
```